# getting all export type info using reflection for golang package

Tags: go, import, reflection

Project structure is like below

root 

  /  
package1

      executor struct 

  /   package2

  model struct

inside package1 want to programmatically read all exported types of package2. I believe it is doable using reflection. Facing issue in finding the import path of package2.

Tried using https://pkg.go.dev/go/importer#pkg-functions importer package using

pkg:= importer.Default().Import("model")
this does not work.

Tried using PkgPath

```html
pkgPath := reflect.TypeOf(model.Policy{}).PkgPath()
cfg := &packages.Config{
        Mode:  packages.NeedTypes | packages.NeedTypesInfo,
        Tests: false,
        Env:   append(os.Environ(), "GO111MODULE=off", "USE_SYSTEM_GO=1",
    }
pkgs, err := packages.Load(cfg, pkgPath)
```

```html
pkg:= importer.Default().Import("model") this does not work.
```

this also does not work.

This is bazel based build system.

Comment: Is it your goal to get runtime type information (using reflection) or to parse types from the source code (using the importer)?

Comment: parse types from source code is the goal.

Comment: Describe how `importer.Default().Import("model")` did not work.  If the call returned an error, then what is that error?

Comment: Reflection is a _runtime_ thing. You cannot do what you want with reflection.